# Calling a function within a function and passing its arguments (*args) - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments, args

I don't see myself that bad in python but I am struggling to figure out what it is wrong in my code.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

def func1(x, params, *args):
    x = x.T
    if args[0] == 'condition':
        params['parameter1'] = False
        args = args[1:]
    else:
        params['parameter1'] = True
    return x, params

def func2(x, *args):
    params = {}
    params['parameter1'] = True
    params['parameter2'] = 'solid'
    params['parameter3'] = 200
    x, params = func1(x, params, args[:])
    print(params)
    print(x)
    print(args)

func2(x, 'condition')
```

The problem I am facing is that the "if" in func1 is not executed. Python does not see that args[0] is equal to the string 'condition' despite that I clearly pass it when calling the func2 on the last line.
Despite that we I print the length of args before If-statement, I get 1 as an indication that there is indeed an argument "condition" being passed.

```
print(len(args)) *# gives 1*
```

I will appreciate your feedback. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First and last step of debugging: Add a `print(args)` to your `func1` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
x, params = func1(x, params, args[:])
```

with

```
x, params = func1(x, params, *args)
```

If you do not use the `*` the value that is stored in `args` in `func1` will be `(('condition',),)` instead of `('condition',)`. Thats also why `print(len(args))` still gives one as output.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It didn't do the trick unfortunately. I am expecting to re-set the parameter1 in the dictionary to "False". But it still gives me "True".

Comment: I also tried to run it and it gives me `False`. Maybe you changed something else during your error search?

Answer (score 1):

In `func2(x, *args):` you must use

```
x, params = func1(x, params, *args)
```

If you use args[:], then you get dict(dict(args)) type object.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for the illustration :*